# How can I retrive data from db with ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to check if a field is just present into db before submit a form.

So I add the keyup event to that field to get data from `db` with `ajax`.

So where I have the form I add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#matricola").keyup(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type:"get",
             url: "getMatricolaAjax.php",
             data: {'type':'user', 'matricola':$("#matricola").val()},
             dataType: "text",
             success: function(result){
                console.log("OK");
                $("#matricola").val("");
                alert("Matricola "+ result +" già presente!!");
             },
             error: function(){
                console.log("KO");
             }
           });
      });
  });
```

And this is my `getMatricolaAjax.php`:

```
<script src='js/jquery-2.1.4.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    require_once FUNCTION_PATH.'/dbFunction.php';

    if($_GET['type'] == "user"){
        $queryMatricolaMatch = 'select * from user where matricola = "'.$_GET['matricola'].'"';
    }else{
        $queryMatricolaMatch = 'select * from 150ore where matricola = "'.$_GET['matricola'].'"';
    }
    echo $queryMatricolaMatch;
    $conn = dbConnect($USERDB, $PASSWORDDB, $NAMEDB);
    $matricola = dbQueryGetResult($queryMatricolaMatch);
    dbDisconnect($conn);

    echo $matricola;
```

It works for half, beacause in `result` I obtain all `html` code from `getMatricolaAjax.php`..

Why??

How can I get only `matricola`??

Comment: im not sure how your dbQueryGetResult() function is set up, but usually querying mysql database returns an array (what you probably think is "all html code") so if you want to get specific result, you need to point to that array key when matching

Comment: As you noticed, the `result` variable contains the output of the php script you call using ajax. If you need other output, you should modify your script or make another script that only returns what you need.

Comment: getMatricolaAjax.php should not contain any output such as script tag, style tag in it. You need to echo only by php.

Comment: you don't need any HTML tags or JavaScript <script src='js/jquery-2.1.4.js' type="text/javascript"></script> in getMatricolaAjax.php. So remove them, then let us know the output you get

Comment: @RNKushwaha Ok!! I remove all import and echo.. But now I have Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) so the respong of ajax enter into error instead success... why?

Comment: No no, you have to keep the  require_once 'config.php'; require_once FUNCTION_PATH.'/dbFunction.php'; lines. remove the <script src='js/jquery-2.1.4.js' type="text/javascript"></script> only and let us know

Answer (score 0):

Comment or remove `dataType: "text"` and try again.

```
   $.ajax({
         type:"get",
         url: "getMatricolaAjax.php",
         data: {'type':'user', 'matricola':$("#matricola").val()},
         // dataType: "text", 
         success: function(result){
            console.log("OK");
            $("#matricola").val("");
            alert("Matricola "+ result +" già presente!!");
         },
```

or else you can use json_encode() in PHP to get data as JSON object array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use POST to check for value in database before submitting a form.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
       $("#matricola").keyup(function (e) { 
         var thevalue = $(this).val();
         $.post('getMatricolaAjax.php',{'type':'user','matricola':thevalue}, 
           function(data) { 
            console.log("OK");
            $("#matricola").val("");
            alert("Matricola "+ data +" già presente!!");
           });
         });
      });
```

And the php file

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once FUNCTION_PATH.'/dbFunction.php';
$conn = dbConnect($USERDB, $PASSWORDDB, $NAMEDB);

if($conn->real_escape_string($_POST['type']) == "user"){
    $queryMatricolaMatch = 'select * from user where matricola = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['matricola']).'"';
}else{
    $queryMatricolaMatch = 'select * from 150ore where matricola = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['matricola']).'"';
}

$matricola = dbQueryGetResult($queryMatricolaMatch);
dbDisconnect($conn);

echo $matricola;
```

This should work, but I have no idea what dbQueryGetResult is supposed to do so you should post it too.
*Note:If you use PDO edit remove 'real_escape_string' function and use other methods of sanitization*